# Node covering in a random graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, covering

Given $N$ nodes randomly placed in a $D\times D$ area, i.e., the position of each node is randomly chosen. Assume that both $N$ and $D$ are sufficiantly large.

An agent can move in the area at constant unit speed. When moving, it marks all nodes within distance $d$ from it ($d$ is Eucliean distance rather than number of hops). It aims at finding an itinerary such that given the time duration $T$, it can mark as many nodes as possible. In other words, the agent wants to find a path of length $l=T$ along which it can mark as many nodes as possile.

Under such setting, if the path is chosen randomly (e.g., the agent goes straightly towards a random direction for the entire time duration $T$), which is a natural strategy, then the number of nodes covered is $\frac{NT}{D^2}$. This gives a reference for comparison. Now I want to derive the expected number of covered nodes (or an upper-bound) for an optimal path, i.e., if the agent strategically chooses an optimal path, what is the number of nodes covered in average?

Comment: Can you please edit to make this more precise.  You are talking about random geometric graphs, right?  If nodes are distributed with Poisson density $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ there is no optimal path: There is a sequence of paths where the number of nodes covered is unbounded.  So you need to specify the domain.  Also, it is not clear whether the agent is restricted to the graph (in which case, how to move in a straight line), or not (in which case, $d$ is Eucliean distances rather than number of hops, and we might as well just talk about node locations and ignore the graph).

Comment: @Carl. Thanks Carl for your comment. I have reformulated the problem.

Comment: Thanks - clearer now.  A couple of further remarks: 1. Fixed $N$ normally behaves similarly to fixed density $\lambda=N/D^2$ but the latter is easier to work with since the nodes in disjoint subsets are independent.  2. The area covered in duration $T$ (assuming far from the boundaries) is $2dT+\pi d^2$ if I understand correctly, so I would expect the average number of nodes covered (without optimising) to be about $(2dT+\pi d^2)N/D^2$.

Comment: The expected number of points covered is directly proportional to the area passed over by the disc of radius $d$ as it is dragged along the path followed by the agent, so this isn't really anything to do with random graphs.  This area doesn't seem to depend very much on the actual path followed, unless you do something obviously silly: for example, tracing an arc of length $l$ of a circle gives the same result whatever the radius $l$ of the circle is, provided $l \leq r$ (to prevent wrap-around).

Comment: @Ben I agree it is not a random graph question.  Choosing a region with a higher than average density of nodes, it is presumably possible to gain a further logarithmic factor.

Comment: @Carl I see now that I essentially duplicated the second half of your comment.  I was interpreting the expectation as being over the random point set for a fixed path, but that probably isn't what was intended.  The two questions are likely roughly equivalent by showing concentration for the number of points in nice regions.

Comment: You might search for: *line transversals of disjoint disks/balls*. A transversal is an object that intersects a collection of other objects.

Comment: @Ben, Carl. I definitely agree that it is not a random graph problem. The point is that the problem itself is NP-complete. So I'd like to find out in a random setting, what is the average number (in order of magnitude, as a function of the density) of covered nodes under an optimal trajectory compared to the baseline random strategy.

Comment: @LinChen, I don't expect that you will be able to do much better than that random strategy (which may as well be deterministic, as fixing the direction in advance shouldn't change anything).  This is because you can only beat that bound by choosing to cover an area with an unusually high density of points, and these are unlikely to exist by Chernoff-type concentration bounds.

Comment: @Ben, I see your points. My thought is that like the bin-and-ball problem where the maximal load is $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$, the optimal trajectory might be logarithmic better.